# Ajv JSONSchemaType with bsonType extenstion

Tags: typescript, mongodb, bson, ajv

I just want to ask if ajv JSONSchemaType supports bsonType extension or is there any way to make it work together?

I just want to let TS validate my JSON schemas but I am also using MongoDB so I need bsonType extension.